# Shader Interp destroys plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a question about the `shader=interp` option. Without the `shader=interp` option I have a smooth 3D plot of my row-wise sorted data, like in this picture:

[image]

Now I want to smooth my plot with the `shader=interp` option and the plot looks like this:

[image]

Can someone explain this behaviour and may give a solution how to fix it?
Here is the Code and the Data:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[unbounded coords=jump, xlabel={Höhe [ft]},ylabel={$V_{TAS}$ [kt]}, zlabel={Anstellwinkel $\alpha$}, width=\textwidth, x dir=reverse, y dir=reverse, grid=minor, x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}, y tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed}, scaled x ticks = false, scaled y ticks = false, colorbar]
        \addplot3[surf, mesh/rows=9, mesh/ordering=colwise, shader=interp] file {Test_Data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{plot:alpha_matrix}
\end{figure}
```

And here the Data file:

```
  1.0000000e+003  7.0000000e+001  2.5688058e+001
  6.0000000e+003  7.0000000e+001  2.7866403e+001
  1.1000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  3.0366514e+001
  1.6000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  3.3003823e+001
  2.1000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  3.5593766e+001
  2.6000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  3.7951777e+001
  3.1000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  3.9893288e+001
  3.6000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  4.1233734e+001
  4.1000000e+004  7.0000000e+001  4.1788549e+001
  1.0000000e+003  7.5000000e+001  2.3734877e+001
  6.0000000e+003  7.5000000e+001  2.5835416e+001
  1.1000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  2.8271941e+001
  1.6000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  3.0886324e+001
  2.1000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  3.3520443e+001
  2.6000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  3.6016171e+001
  3.1000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  3.8215383e+001
  3.6000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  3.9959956e+001
  4.1000000e+004  7.5000000e+001  4.1091763e+001
  1.0000000e+003  8.0000000e+001  2.1895370e+001
  6.0000000e+003  8.0000000e+001  2.3920039e+001
  1.1000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  2.6292123e+001
  1.6000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  2.8877999e+001
  2.1000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  3.1544041e+001
  2.6000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  3.4156624e+001
  3.1000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  3.6582122e+001
  3.6000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  3.8686912e+001
  4.1000000e+004  8.0000000e+001  4.0337367e+001
  1.0000000e+003  8.5000000e+001  2.0165834e+001
  6.0000000e+003  8.5000000e+001  2.2116549e+001
  1.1000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  2.4423468e+001
  1.6000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  2.6975594e+001
  2.1000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  2.9661929e+001
  2.6000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  3.2371476e+001
  3.1000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  3.4993235e+001
  3.6000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  3.7416210e+001
  4.1000000e+004  8.5000000e+001  3.9529403e+001
  1.0000000e+003  8.7500000e+001  1.9341147e+001
  6.0000000e+003  8.7500000e+001  2.1255599e+001
  1.1000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  2.3529704e+001
  1.6000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  2.6063096e+001
  2.1000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  2.8755410e+001
  2.6000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  3.1506282e+001
  3.1000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  3.4215347e+001
  3.6000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  3.6782240e+001
  4.1000000e+004  8.7500000e+001  3.9106596e+001
  1.0000000e+003  9.0000000e+001  1.8542564e+001
  6.0000000e+003  9.0000000e+001  2.0421226e+001
  1.1000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  2.2662382e+001
  1.6000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  2.5175857e+001
  2.1000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  2.7871476e+001
  2.6000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  3.0659066e+001
  3.1000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  3.3448451e+001
  3.6000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  3.6149459e+001
  4.1000000e+004  9.0000000e+001  3.8671913e+001
  1.0000000e+003  9.2500000e+001  1.7769620e+001
  6.0000000e+003  9.2500000e+001  1.9612965e+001
  1.1000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  2.1821055e+001
  1.6000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  2.4313472e+001
  2.1000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  2.7009799e+001
  2.6000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  2.9829619e+001
  3.1000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  3.2692514e+001
  3.6000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  3.5518066e+001
  4.1000000e+004  9.2500000e+001  3.8225859e+001
  1.0000000e+003  9.5000000e+001  1.7021854e+001
  6.0000000e+003  9.5000000e+001  1.8830350e+001
  1.1000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  2.1005272e+001
  1.6000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  2.3475534e+001
  2.1000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  2.6170050e+001
  2.6000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  2.9017734e+001
  3.1000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  3.1947501e+001
  3.6000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  3.4888264e+001
  4.1000000e+004  9.5000000e+001  3.7768938e+001
  1.0000000e+003  9.7500000e+001  1.6298801e+001
  6.0000000e+003  9.7500000e+001  1.8072917e+001
  1.1000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  2.0214585e+001
  1.6000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  2.2661637e+001
  2.1000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  2.5351900e+001
  2.6000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  2.8223204e+001
  3.1000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  3.1213379e+001
  3.6000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  3.4260253e+001
  4.1000000e+004  9.7500000e+001  3.7301657e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.0000000e+002  1.5600000e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.0000000e+002  1.7340200e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  1.9448545e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  2.1871373e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  2.4555019e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  2.7445820e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  3.0490114e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  3.3634235e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.0000000e+002  3.6824520e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.0250000e+002  1.4924986e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.0250000e+002  1.6631733e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  1.8706702e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  2.1104336e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  2.3779079e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  2.6685376e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  2.9777671e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  3.3010409e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.0250000e+002  3.6338033e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.0500000e+002  1.4273297e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.0500000e+002  1.5947053e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  1.7988607e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  2.0360119e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  2.3023751e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  2.5941664e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  2.9076019e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  3.2388977e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.0500000e+002  3.5842700e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.0750000e+002  1.3644470e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.0750000e+002  1.5285694e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  1.7293811e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  1.9638316e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  2.2288706e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  2.5214476e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  2.8385122e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  3.1770140e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.0750000e+002  3.5339027e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.1000000e+002  1.3038042e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.1000000e+002  1.4647191e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  1.6621865e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  1.8938521e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  2.1573615e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  2.4503604e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  2.7704947e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  3.1154100e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.1000000e+002  3.4827519e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.1500000e+002  1.1890527e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.1500000e+002  1.3436892e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  1.5344726e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  1.7603324e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  2.0201978e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  2.3129981e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  2.6376627e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  2.9931209e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.1500000e+002  3.3783020e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.2000000e+002  1.0827050e+001
  6.0000000e+003  1.2000000e+002  1.2312435e+001
  1.1000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  1.4153598e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  1.6351276e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  1.8906210e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  2.1819135e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  2.5090790e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  2.8721913e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.2000000e+002  3.2713243e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.4000000e+002  7.3394180e+000
  6.0000000e+003  1.4000000e+002  8.5986109e+000
  1.1000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  1.0177316e+001
  1.6000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  1.2109512e+001
  2.1000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  1.4429182e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  1.7170304e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  2.0366859e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  2.4052828e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.4000000e+002  2.8262191e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.6000000e+002  4.9000000e+000
  6.0000000e+003  1.6000000e+002  5.9605944e+000
  1.1000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  7.2897337e+000
  1.6000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  8.9378824e+000
  2.1000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  1.0955505e+001
  2.6000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  1.3393065e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  1.6301028e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  1.9729858e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.6000000e+002  2.3730019e+001
  1.0000000e+003  1.8000000e+002  3.2716931e+000
  6.0000000e+003  1.8000000e+002  4.1602516e+000
  1.1000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  5.2608862e+000
  1.6000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  6.6281877e+000
  2.1000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  8.3167472e+000
  2.6000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  1.0381155e+001
  3.1000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  1.2876003e+001
  3.6000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  1.5855882e+001
  4.1000000e+004  1.8000000e+002  1.9375382e+001
  1.0000000e+003  2.0000000e+002  2.2173942e+000
  6.0000000e+003  2.0000000e+002  2.9594490e+000
  1.1000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  3.8608074e+000
  1.6000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  4.9722303e+000
  2.1000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  6.3444783e+000
  2.6000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  8.0283121e+000
  3.1000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  1.0074492e+001
  3.6000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  1.2533780e+001
  4.1000000e+004  2.0000000e+002  1.5456935e+001
  1.0000000e+003  2.2000000e+002  1.5000000e+000
  6.0000000e+003  2.2000000e+002  2.1200528e+000
  1.1000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  2.8595319e+000
  1.6000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  3.7618118e+000
  2.1000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  4.8702671e+000
  2.6000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  6.2282724e+000
  3.1000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  7.8792025e+000
  3.6000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  9.8664318e+000
  4.1000000e+004  2.2000000e+002  1.2233335e+001
  1.0000000e+003  2.4000000e+002  9.2025132e-001
  6.0000000e+003  2.4000000e+002  1.4419050e+000
  1.1000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  2.0615980e+000
  1.6000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  2.8156902e+000
  2.1000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  3.7405416e+000
  2.6000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  4.8725121e+000
  3.1000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  6.2479616e+000
  3.6000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  7.9032500e+000
  4.1000000e+004  2.4000000e+002  9.8747373e+000
  1.0000000e+003  2.6000000e+002  4.3026455e-001
  6.0000000e+003  2.6000000e+002  8.7674866e-001
  1.1000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  1.4095605e+000
  1.6000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  2.0604499e+000
  2.1000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  2.8611668e+000
  2.6000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  3.8434611e+000
  3.1000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  5.0390827e+000
  3.6000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  6.4797814e+000
  4.1000000e+004  2.6000000e+002  8.1973072e+000
  1.0000000e+003  2.8000000e+002  2.0000000e-002
  6.0000000e+003  2.8000000e+002  4.1430230e-001
  1.1000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  8.8047802e-001
  1.6000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  1.4496314e+000
  2.1000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  2.1528666e+000
  2.6000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  3.0212879e+000
  3.1000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  4.0859996e+000
  3.6000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  5.3781058e+000
  4.1000000e+004  2.8000000e+002  6.9287108e+000
  1.0000000e+003  3.0000000e+002 -3.1788360e-001
  6.0000000e+003  3.0000000e+002  4.3362535e-002
  1.1000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  4.5282909e-001
  1.6000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  9.4480874e-001
  2.1000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  1.5535942e+000
  2.6000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  2.3134780e+000
  3.1000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  3.2587529e+000
  3.6000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  4.4237116e+000
  4.1000000e+004  3.0000000e+002  5.8426467e+000
  1.0000000e+003  3.2000000e+002 -5.7993386e-001
  6.0000000e+003  3.2000000e+002 -2.5096184e-001
  1.1000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  1.1077108e-001
  1.6000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  5.3968978e-001
  2.1000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  1.0702191e+000
  2.6000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  1.7367840e+000
  3.1000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  2.5738093e+000
  3.6000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  3.6157199e+000
  4.1000000e+004  3.2000000e+002  4.8969406e+000
  1.0000000e+003  3.4000000e+002 -7.6000000e-001
  6.0000000e+003  3.4000000e+002 -4.8448394e-001
  1.1000000e+004  3.4000000e+002 -1.6011889e-001
  1.6000000e+004  3.4000000e+002  2.3601569e-001
  2.1000000e+004  3.4000000e+002  7.2684032e-001
  2.6000000e+004  3.4000000e+002  1.3352755e+000
  3.1000000e+004  3.4000000e+002  2.0842419e+000
  3.6000000e+004  3.4000000e+002  2.9966599e+000
  4.1000000e+004  3.4000000e+002  4.0954502e+000
  1.0000000e+003  3.6000000e+002 -8.6130952e-001
  6.0000000e+003  3.6000000e+002 -6.7273139e-001
  1.1000000e+004  3.6000000e+002 -3.7509440e-001
  1.6000000e+004  3.6000000e+002  2.7147413e-002
  2.1000000e+004  3.6000000e+002  5.2954002e-001
  2.6000000e+004  3.6000000e+002  1.1276294e+000
  3.1000000e+004  3.6000000e+002  1.8169614e+000
  3.6000000e+004  3.6000000e+002  2.5930822e+000
  4.1000000e+004  3.6000000e+002  3.4515376e+000
  1.0000000e+003  3.8000000e+002 -9.2460317e-001
  6.0000000e+003  3.8000000e+002 -8.3008987e-001
  1.1000000e+004  3.8000000e+002 -5.5273187e-001
  1.6000000e+004  3.8000000e+002 -1.2707510e-001
  2.1000000e+004  3.8000000e+002  4.1233453e-001
  2.6000000e+004  3.8000000e+002  1.0309511e+000
  3.1000000e+004  3.8000000e+002  1.6942287e+000
  3.6000000e+004  3.8000000e+002  2.3676214e+000
  4.1000000e+004  3.8000000e+002  3.0165834e+000
  1.0000000e+003  4.0000000e+002 -1.0000000e+000
  6.0000000e+003  4.0000000e+002 -9.7065951e-001
  1.1000000e+004  4.0000000e+002 -7.1243839e-001
  1.6000000e+004  4.0000000e+002 -2.7519216e-001
  2.1000000e+004  4.0000000e+002  2.9122367e-001
  2.6000000e+004  4.0000000e+002  9.3695356e-001
  3.1000000e+004  4.0000000e+002  1.6121420e+000
  3.6000000e+004  4.0000000e+002  2.2669335e+000
  4.1000000e+004  4.0000000e+002  2.8514724e+000
  1.0000000e+003  4.2000000e+002 -1.1376190e+000
  6.0000000e+003  4.2000000e+002 -1.1085405e+000
  1.1000000e+004  4.2000000e+002 -8.7362107e-001
  1.6000000e+004  4.2000000e+002 -4.6574407e-001
  2.1000000e+004  4.2000000e+002  8.2207224e-002
  2.6000000e+004  4.2000000e+002  7.3734954e-001
  3.1000000e+004  4.2000000e+002  1.4667996e+000
  3.6000000e+004  4.2000000e+002  2.2376741e+000
  4.1000000e+004  4.2000000e+002  3.0170898e+000
  1.0000000e+003  4.4000000e+002 -1.3875794e+000
  6.0000000e+003  4.4000000e+002 -1.2578330e+000
  1.1000000e+004  4.4000000e+002 -1.0556870e+000
  1.6000000e+004  4.4000000e+002 -7.4727116e-001
  2.1000000e+004  4.4000000e+002 -2.9871499e-001
  2.6000000e+004  4.4000000e+002  3.2385188e-001
  3.1000000e+004  4.4000000e+002  1.1542998e+000
  3.6000000e+004  4.4000000e+002  2.2264993e+000
  4.1000000e+004  4.4000000e+002  3.5743205e+000
  1.0000000e+003  4.6000000e+002 -1.8000000e+000
  6.0000000e+003  4.6000000e+002 -1.4326371e+000
  1.1000000e+004  4.6000000e+002 -1.2780433e+000
  1.6000000e+004  4.6000000e+002 -1.1683137e+000
  2.1000000e+004  4.6000000e+002 -9.3554317e-001
  2.6000000e+004  4.6000000e+002 -4.1182663e-001
  3.1000000e+004  4.6000000e+002  5.7074097e-001
  3.6000000e+004  4.6000000e+002  2.1800647e+000
  4.1000000e+004  4.6000000e+002  4.5840495e+000
  1.0000000e+003  4.8000000e+002 -2.4250000e+000
  6.0000000e+003  4.8000000e+002 -1.6470530e+000
  1.1000000e+004  4.8000000e+002 -1.5600971e+000
  1.6000000e+004  4.8000000e+002 -1.7774121e+000
  2.1000000e+004  4.8000000e+002 -1.9122775e+000
  2.6000000e+004  4.8000000e+002 -1.5779731e+000
  3.1000000e+004  4.8000000e+002 -3.8777867e-001
  3.6000000e+004  4.8000000e+002  2.0450262e+000
  4.1000000e+004  4.8000000e+002  6.1071618e+000
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like your PDF viewer is aliasing. Can you try in some other viewer, preferably Acrobat reader?

Comment: Thank you very much. That's it. I worked with Sumatra... but with Adobe its nice and clean. Is there any workaround for Sumatra?

Comment: This "strange behavior" was introduced with PGFPlots v1.14 as Christian Feuersänger has told me. One of the reasons was to get rid of a bunch of compatibility code, but has "this" downside. Currently I don't know any workaround, but have written a feature request in the Issue Tracker of SumatraPDF (see [here](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/595)). Because of that I am voting to close this question as off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a PDF viewer issue (with SumatraPDF in this case).

Comment: @StefanPinnow The change which is reveals a bug in SumatraPdf is unrelated to that conversion about "get rid of compatibility code but accept downside". That conversion between us lead to a rollback; there is no removal of compatibility code and there is no downside. This remark is primarily for the audience to remove any potential doubts about the priority of compatibility in pgfplots.

Comment: The different comes in due to an optimization in pgfplots 1.14: pgfplots now makes use of a bigger number range for color data (namely the range [0,1000.0000] instead of [0,1.0000]) which allows higher precision in color transitions. However, sumatrapdf apparently fails to decode such functions.

Comment: A workaround in pgfplots would be to add `\makeatletter
\def\pgfplotscolormappdfmax{1}
\def\pgfplotscolormappdfmax@inv{1000}` _after_ `pgfplots` has been loaded. This will revert to the old functionality, and this allows SumatraPdf to render the image correctly. Note that this workaround is compatible with all other views (basically, it restores the behavior up to and including pgfplots 1.13).

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger, thank you very much for correcting my statement. (This was added from my mind without checking our emails in detail.) Hope that helps the developers of SumatraPDF to fix "the bug".

Comment: For the record: I have added this issue to the SumatraPDF tracker as [Issue #595](https://github.com/sumatrapdfreader/sumatrapdf/issues/595).

Comment: I am aware that this question and the comments are 2 years old, but: It seems like the same issue prevails. For me, the plots with pgfplots 1.14 and later are not displayed correctly in any of both MuPDF and Zathura. It seems strange that there should be so many PDF viewers that are wrong here.

Comment: For the record: I've raised an issue with the MuPDF tracker, [here](https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=699947).

Comment: Same issue, SumatraPDF v3.2, 64-bit. Opens cleanly in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Edit: Installed v3.3.3, issue resolved.